# onActivityResult() always return 0 after I saved the contact

Tags: android

there are similar questions out there but I can't find an answer for this. Thanks in advance for the help.

I am trying to get data information from the newly added contact.
Following is my snippet code:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {                   
            Intent addContactIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
            addContactIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
            addContactIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.POSTAL , address);
            startActivityForResult(addContactIntent, ADD_NEW_CONTACT);
        }
    });
```

I call the Contact and put the address in the "address" field.

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ADD_NEW_CONTACT) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

However, the resultCode is ALWAYS 0 whenever I save the contact (note that there is no "save" button in the contact app, I just press the 'back' button to save it). I know it's been saved as I can see the saved contact in the contacts app. (Of course, it return 0 when I chose the "Discard").

Comment: Ignoring the `resultCode`, is `data` non-null and does it contain a result Uri? (I would check if `data.getData()` gives you something.)

Comment: I think the data.getData() is null as I get the error:
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method '....Intent.getData()' on a null object reference.

Comment: Someone is saying: "External email apps like Gmail app never implemented the response code logic. So Such apps will always return the default resultcode which is RESULT_CANCELED"

Is that true? If it is, is there any work around?

Comment: FYI, my code works with the example from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html, but this example is picking up contact instead of adding a new contacts.

Comment: It's possible the contacts application did not implement returning the result. In that case I don't know what you could do to work around the problem, other than to implement your own UI for creating a contact and writing it to the ContactsProvider yourself. (Note that this will require you to have the WRITE_CONTACTS permission)

Comment: @Karakuri Thanks for your suggestion and that's what I am going to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the very same problem. The solution, in my case, was to ignore Activity.RESULT_OK and focus on two values I knew would be available, viz requestCode and an Address (Contact tel number).

Then in the onActivityResult, create a query on the Contacts API using the Contact.Address to locate the added/edited Contact and extract whatever data I required in that fashion. (Of course if the OP deleted a Contact this would not work!)

It appears in this OP's case the POSTAL column is known prior to startActivityForResult, so it follows that the Contacts query should be based on that data.

Hope this helps!